# Error on missing return statement under GCC

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, return

How do I generate an error for a missing return statement under GCC?

> cpfsfuse.c:184: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void

I'm able to return errors for implicit function declaration (`-Werror-implicit-function-declaration`), and I'm aware of a `-Werror=` switch, but I can't locate an appropriate warning to promote to error status.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to use the `-fdiagnostics-show-option` option to show the correct flag for the `Werror=` switch. Taken from [this](http://blog.flameeyes.eu/2008/11/13/gcc-features-and-shortcomings) blog post:

```
gcc -x c -Wall -Wextra -fdiagnostics-show-option -c -o /dev/null - <<EOF
int foo() {
}
EOF
```

#### Output

```
<stdin> In function ‘foo’:
<stdin>:2: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Actually, it looks like the `return-type` flag may be the one you want.

Comment: Note that with -Wreturn-type you won't get any warnings for the main() function when the return statement is missing.

Comment: I have a GoogleTest suite that was generating false positives in a CI job because of this default return in `main()`. Any flags you know of to enforce explicit returns in `main()` too?