# Why does'nt the compiler throw error for not returning this pointer for a function whose return type is classname&

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, chaining, constructor-chaining

Why does'nt the compiler throw error for not returning this pointer for a function whose return type is classname&

Ex: In the functions readonly , readwrite etc , even though we comment return *this and do not return anything , this seems to work fine and also the chaining mechanism is perfectly working in the main function.

Will these functions return *this automatically ?

```
class OpenFile {
public:
  OpenFile(const std::string& filename);

  OpenFile& readonly();  // changes readonly_ to true
  OpenFile& readwrite(); // changes readonly_ to false
  OpenFile& createIfNotExist();
  OpenFile& blockSize(unsigned nbytes);

private:
  friend class File;
  std::string filename_;
  bool readonly_;          // defaults to false [for example]
  bool createIfNotExist_;  // defaults to false [for example]

  unsigned blockSize_;     // defaults to 4096 [for example]

};
inline OpenFile::OpenFile(const std::string& filename)
  : filename_         (filename)
  , readonly_         (false)
  , createIfNotExist_ (false)
  , blockSize_        (4096u)
{ }
inline OpenFile& OpenFile::readonly()
{ readonly_ = true; return *this; }
inline OpenFile& OpenFile::readwrite()
{ readonly_ = false; return *this; }
inline OpenFile& OpenFile::createIfNotExist()
{ createIfNotExist_ = true; return *this; }
inline OpenFile& OpenFile::blockSize(unsigned nbytes)
{ blockSize_ = nbytes; return *this; }

main()
{
//OpenFile *obj = new OpenFile();
  OpenFile f = OpenFile("foo.txt")
       .readonly()
       .createIfNotExist()
       .blockSize(1024);
}
```

Deleting return statement will not effect the code at all, Something like this

```
inline OpenFile& OpenFile::readonly()
{ readonly_ = true;  }
inline OpenFile& OpenFile::readwrite()
{ readonly_ = false;  }
inline OpenFile& OpenFile::createIfNotExist()
{ createIfNotExist_ = true; }
inline OpenFile& OpenFile::blockSize(unsigned nbytes)
{ blockSize_ = nbytes;  }
```

How is the compiler treating these functions or is it automatically returning *this by looking at the return type?

Comment: You are supposed to get something like "missing return statement on non-void function". Chances are you can add some warnings and treat warnings as errors to fix this.

Comment: The compiler should at least be emitting a warning, which you can turn into an error if you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3487031/996886

Answer (score 4):

> How is the compiler treating these functions

in an undefined way

> or is it automatically returning *this by looking at the return type?

no. the program's behaviour is not predictable and certainly won't be correct.

> but it seems to work

in an unoptimised build, very likely. The register holding the `this` pointer is probably not being modified.

Wait until the optimiser starts inlining your code in your release build. Enjoy the fireworks.

> Why doesn't the compiler complain?

If you enable warnings, it will. You should always enable all warnings. They help you to avoid incorrect code:

```
/tmp/gcc-explorer-compiler116311-75-17mquww/example.cpp: In member function 'OpenFile& OpenFile::readonly()':
28 : warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
{ readonly_ = true; }
^
Compiled ok
```

From §6.6.3 (2):

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in
>   undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

Comment: _They help you to avoid incorrect code_ Well... they help you avoid _obviously_ incorrect code. :)